# Change Table Cell width

Tags: tables, width

[image]

I want to replicate this in latex, where the cell of the bottom row is not as wide as the others on top, so far my code and output is:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l | p{13cm}|}
\hline
    {Tested By} & {SQA Team}\\    
\hline
    {Test Type} & {Acceptance Test}\\    
\hline
    {Test Case Number} & {TC-1.1 Create a client successfully}\\    
\hline
    {Test Case Description} & {This test case is used to check if a visitor can create a client with the system}\\    
\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Item(s) to be tested}\\
\hline
    {1.} & {SRS 3.1.1.1}\\    
\hline


\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|ll| p{13cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{Gray0}Tested By} & {SQA Team}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{Gray0}Test Type} & {Acceptance Test}\\    
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{Gray0}Test Case Number} & {TC-1.1 Create a client successfully}\\    
\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{Gray0}Test Case Description} & {This test case is used to check if a visitor can create a client with the system}\\    
\hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Gray0}Item(s) to be tested}\\
\hline
1.\hspace{1cm} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\fcolorbox{white}{DeepSkyBlue1}{SRS 3.1.1.1}}\\    
\hline


\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this. My preference would be to simply fake the last row using `\makebox` and `\vrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}

\newcommand{\myrow}[2]% #1=first column, #2=second column
{\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\makebox[1cm][l]{#1}\hspace{\tabcolsep}\vrule\hspace{\tabcolsep}#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l | p{13cm}|}
\hline
    {Tested By} & {SQA Team}\\    
\hline
    {Test Type} & {Acceptance Test}\\    
\hline
    {Test Case Number} & {TC-1.1 Create a client successfully}\\    
\hline
    {Test Case Description} & {This test case is used to check if a visitor can create a client with the system}\\    
\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Item(s) to be tested}\\
\hline
    \myrow{1.}{SRS 3.1.1.1 }\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to think that there are three columns; in rows 1--4, the first column spans two columns, and in row 5 onwards, the second column spans two column. Here is how to implement this in ConTeXt (the solution should be easy to port to LaTeX):

```
\startsetups testing
  \setupTABLE[toffset=0.5ex, boffset=0.5ex]
  \setupTABLE[column][1][width=4em]
  \setupTABLE[column][2][width=6em]
  \setupTABLE[column][3][width=broad]

  \setupTABLE[1,2][1,2,3,4][background=color, backgroundcolor=gray]
  \setupTABLE[row][5][align=middle, background=color, backgroundcolor=gray]
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTABLE[setups=testing]
  \NC[nc=2] Tested By \NC SQA Team \NC \NR
  \NC[nc=2] Test Type \NC Acceptance Test \NC \NR
  \NC[nc=2] Test Case Number \NC TC-1.1 Create a client successfully \NC \NR
  \NC[nc=2] Test Case Description \NC This test case is used to check if a visitor can create a client with the system \NC \NR
  \NC[nc=3] Item(s) to be tested \NC \NR
  \NC 1. \NC[nc=2] SRS 3.1.1.1 \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]